# very stuck with cocoapods / ruby setup

Tags: cocoapods

This was working fine and then suddenly it wasn't. I wish i knew why. Really stuck and cannot find anything online. I'm working on an ObjectiveC project. I've tried reseting everything with:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall ruby
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

then

```
$ sudo gem install ruby
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ sudo gem update ruby
$ sudo gem update cocoapods
```

then i when in my projects directory i run

```
$pod install
```

and get the following error. I get this on all projects.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- cocoapods-core (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:8:in `<module:Pod>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas/clues/answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does fresh install of cocoapods help ? (http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started)

Comment: No luck :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you solve this eventually?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165016/cant-get-to-work-cocoapods-and-yosemite/32236562#32236562

Answer (score 17):

I reinstalled cocoa pods by running

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core cocoapods-downloader cocoapods
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

That resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing one of CocoaPod's dependencies. You should be able to install it with:

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods-core
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop using "sudo" for tasks such as "gem install" etc. Here is a little tutorial on how to fix your ruby to ensure that you are not going to see issues with permissions for cocoapods (and other gems):

[Can't get to work CocoaPods and Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165016/cant-get-to-work-cocoapods-and-yosemite/32236562#32236562)