# Can't get to work CocoaPods and Yosemite

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, xcode6, cocoapods

I already tried this steps:

1. Open Xcode 6 Open Preferences
2. Click the Locations tab
3. Change the Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
4. Uninstall cocoapods
5. a. $sudo gem uninstall cocoapods Install xcodeproj
6. a. $ sudo gem install
7. xcodeproj Install cocoapods
8. a. $ sudo gem install cocoapods
9. Run pod --version to verify that it worked

But I'm still gettings this when I do pod install or pod --version:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case someone else got the same issue, I did this to fix my issue:

1. Update Gems

   `sudo gem update --system`
2. Uninstalled xcodeproj

   `sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj`
3. Make sure to select All versions
4. Uninstalled Cocoapods

   `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
5. Install xcodeproj

   `sudo gem install xcodeproj`
6. Install cocoapods

   `sudo gem install cocoapods`
7. Run

   `pod --version to test.`

Comment: If this is how you fixed your issue, be sure to check it as the answer to your question.

Comment: It does not let me choose my answer until 2 days passed.

Comment: This no longer works.

I need to use 0.33.1 for backwards compat purposes.

Answer (score 20):

Running these 2 lines will resolve your problem

> sudo gem update --system
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 2):

I had to uninstall the entire dependency chain for cocoapods to get it to work.

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

see [Uninstall all installed gems, in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx)

Answer (score 2):

Many of this issues are because of system-wide ruby installation and it forces developers to use "sudo" all the time (well, how many times we did "**sudo** gem install cocoapods --pre"). I recently had the same issue trying to install a pre-released version of cocoapods (permissions were messed up). So here is a approached that worked for me.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj 
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Let's restore Apple's ruby installation, the following is for Yosemite that has 2.0 ruby by default 
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
$ sudo rm Current
$ sudo ln -s 2.0 Current 
$ brew install ruby
```

(closing and opening terminal window sometimes help)

```
$ which ruby
```

should display **/usr/local/bin/ruby**
(should point to "local" directory now, not to "/usr/bin", if this is not the case for you, make sure to modify path order)

Now you should be able to install xcodeproj and cocoapods without using "sudo":

```
$ gem install xcodeproj --pre
$ gem install cocoapods --pre
```

(I'm using pre-released version, just remove --pre if you want to use releases instead).

Enjoy :)

Comment: Great tutorial! Thank you! Minor change, it should say `sudo gem uninstall`

Comment: Thanks AnthonyM, I was typing too fast.

Answer (score 0):

The error `'require': cannot load such file` indicates that you some missing or broken gem package. You can probably fix it by re-installing cocoapods:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods # Follow by sudo if necessary
gem install cocoapods --verbose # Follow by sudo if necessary
```

And make sure that your xcodeproj is present:

```
gem install xcodeproj --verbose # Follow by sudo if necessary
```

---

If won't help, try to install it by using older Ruby:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.12/bin/gem /usr/bin/gem18
sudo gem18 install cocoapods
```

See:

- [Managing Rails Versions and Gems](http://railsapps.github.io/managing-rails-versions-gems.html)

Answer (score -2):

You just have to execute this commande before :

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This will update all outdated gems