# How do I use cocoapods 0.33.1 on Yosemite?

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

Because of the breaking changes cocoapods 0.34.x introduces, I need to continue using 0.33.1 following my upgrade to Yosemite.

Unfortunately, running `pod install` produces this output:

`` $ pod install
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ``

I have Xcode 6.1 and latest command line tools.  The answer to the following question no longer works: [Can't get to work CocoaPods and Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165016/cant-get-to-work-cocoapods-and-yosemite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems the easiest solution is to install a Ruby environment manager.  This allows the appropriate Ruby version to be loaded when cocoapods asks for it.  I haven't dug too deep, but it seems the version CP is looking for is incompatible. (???)  Anyway, installing [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x) immediately solved my problem.

I chose rbenv but there's another called RVM.  rbenv did a good job explaining the differences between the two, however.

Comment: Which version of ruby did you install?

Comment: I had already installed the latest 2.1.3 through `brew install ruby`, before installing `rbenv`. And 2.0 comes with Yosemite.

Comment: Still not working for me. Did you leave any steps out?

Comment: Not at all.  I installed `rbenv` and cocoapods magically started working.  I'm afraid I can't offer more info.  Is the error exactly the same as mine?

Comment: Yes, same error. I ended up migrating to the new version of cocoapods and worked around the problems.