# can't run pod setup - cannot load such file -- cocoapods-core (LoadError)

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapods so I can install a firebase plugin for my cordova app. I ran `sudo gem install cocoapods` and the gem was successfully installed. then when I tried to run `pod setup` it gave me some error, tried googling the solution, one of them was to uninstall cocoapods and run `sudo gem update --system`. did that, re-installed cocoapods, ran `pod setup` again, but now i'm getting a different error. this is what my terminal shows me after running `pod setup`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
10: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
 9: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
 8: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
 7: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/pod:23:in `load'
 6: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
 5: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
 4: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
 3: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
 2: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods.rb:23:in `<module:Pod>'
 1: from /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
 /Users/almiraputrisandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- cocoapods-core (LoadError)
```

I can't seem to find the solution for this, so if anyone knows a solution, please help me! My Macbook's OS is HighSierra 10.13.6. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved my problem by running the following:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core cocoapods-downloader cocoapods
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

if you get a `LoadError - cannot load such file -- cocoapods_deintegrate` error after running `pod install` after running the 2 commands above, run this command to solve the problem:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

Thank you to these two answers that helped me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232410/8076737
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5111#issuecomment-204694892

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Cocoapods doesn't like using Ruby installed via *rvm* or *rbenv*. If you're using these version managers for Ruby switch to the system Ruby

**For rvm**

```
rvm use system
```

**For rbenv**

```
rbenv global system
```

You'll probably want to switch back after you're done as system Ruby is terrible for development and if you're using rbenv/rvm you're likely doing Ruby development.

After switching to system Ruby pod setup worked fine for me.

*edit*: In general doing `sudo anything` is very bad practice. If you're required to do that your environment is setup wrong and while it may get you past this problem more bigger problems are heading your way.